# Multiple MPI communications and performance

Tags: performance, mpi

I think communicating a buffer of, say, 100 bytes in size with one MPI_Send()/MPI_Recv() call is faster than communicating a buffer of 10 bytes in size with ten MPI_Send()/MPI_Recv() calls. But what if instead of 100 byes, we want to communicate 100 KB or 100 MB or more? At what point the communication of 10 byes with ten MPI calls is faster? Are there general rules of thumb helping us in these kinds of comparisons leading to writing faster codes?

I ask this because there are cases when the programmer has to choose between communicating a large amount of data at once, and a smaller total amount of data via more than one communication.

Answer (score 2):

You may assume that multiple calls will **never** be faster than a single call for the same total volume. The simple reason is that an MPI implementation could simply split up a single call into multiple calls internally if it were faster this way<sup>1</sup>. In general it is advisable to use the MPI API in the most high-level way possible, i.e., collectives instead of p2p, using custom compound datatypes instead of individual messages etc.. This also makes sure the program is most portable.

That said, if you have a specific idea how to improve performance via low-level tweaking, you should **measure** with your specific implementation, on your specific system. After all, your implementation may have a specific issue with larger messages. But you should prefer to achieve the improvement through system-specific tuning (e.g. implementation specific eager message thresholds) as this doesn't pollute the source code.

<sup>1: 
If you include data generation/consumption in your considerations, it is conceivable that multiple calls are faster due to pipelining or caching effects. But this this most probably negligible.</sup>

Comment: If a message does not have to be fully received in order to start processing it, and your library implements a progress thread, then it could be more efficient to split your message so you can start processing it earlier and overlap computations and communications.

Comment: That is a good point. I was not considering pipelining initial because the question was limited to standard sends/receives (and focused on communication only, not including any computational part). But in combination with eager (partial) sends, this is a conceivable effect.